# How to speed up PostGIS clipping of out-db rasters?

Tags: postgis, raster, gdal, clip

I'm clipping (and unioning) thousands of tiled raster files that are stored in an out-db PostgreSQL/PostGIS database located on a SSD.  I want to use PostgreSQL but I found that PostGIS is taking almost three times as long to clip than the gdalwarp.exe utility.

Is there something I can do to get PostgreSQL to perform closer to gdalwarp.exe?

Using gdalwarp.exe to clip raster takes 0.36 seconds versus the SQL query that takes about 1.0 second to complete. The envelope intersects with the raster. The raster is a 1024x1024 JP2OpenJPEG file.

I'm using Postgres 12.4 and PostGIS 3.0 on Windows 10.

I've tried adjusting various configuration settings in the Postgres.conf file (shared_buffers, work_mem, etc.) but couldn't find anything that made a difference.
I tried smaller tile sizes when setting up the out-db images but that actually slowed down the query.

```
gdalwarp.exe -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff -te 103.878150, 1.819093, 103.904514, 1.846015  rasterInput.jp2  clippedRaster.tiff
```

```
SELECT ST_Clip(rast, ST_MakeEnvelope(103.878150, 1.819093, 103.904514, 1.846015, 4326), true) 
FROM _imagery 
WHERE rid = 47300       -- rasterInput.jp2

EXPLAIN ANALYZE:
Index Scan using _imagery_pkey on _imagery  (cost=0.42..2.89 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=1010.391..1010.887 rows=1 loops=1)
Index Cond: (rid = 47300)
Planning Time: 0.414 ms
Execution Time: 1010.939 ms
```